# Remove an object from the array then update the property of all objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, functional-programming, ramda.js

I want to remove an object by id from an array and then update the position property for all objects. For example I have an array like:

```
const arr = [
  {id: 10, position: 1},
  {id: 11, position: 2},
  {id: 12, position: 3},
  {id: 13, position: 4}
]
```

**Example:** First I need to remove the object with id 12 then change the position property for each object. Result:

```
const arr = [
  {id: 10, position: 1},
  {id: 11, position: 2},
  {id: 13, position: 3}
]
```

**My attempt:**

```
const fn = id => pipe(
  reject(propEq('id', id)),
  map((item, key) => evolve({position: key}))
);
```

Comment: does it work? if not, what do you get?

Comment: Using ramda is a requirement or a preference?

Comment: @NinaScholz, it returns an array with functions instead of an array of objects, the problem starts with a map function when I try to update the 'position' property

Comment: @Eldar, requirement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a `mapIndexed` function by applying `R.addIndex` to `R.map`. This is needed because `R.map` doesn't pass the current index to the callback function.

In addition, you'll need to pass a function to `R.evolve` to set the `position` (via `R.always` or an arrow function), and you'll also need to pass the `item` to evolve:

```js
const { pipe, reject, propEq, addIndex, map, evolve, always } = R;

const mapIndexed = addIndex(map);

const fn = id => pipe(
  reject(propEq('id', id)),
  mapIndexed((item, key) => evolve({ position: always(key + 1) }, item))
);

const arr = [{"id":10,"position":1},{"id":11,"position":2},{"id":12,"position":3},{"id":13,"position":4}];

const result = fn(11)(arr);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

I would skip `R.evolve` in this case, and use spread on the `item` to generate the new object, and assign the new `position`:

```js
const { pipe, reject, propEq, addIndex, map } = R;

const mapIndexed = addIndex(map);

const fn = id => pipe(
  reject(propEq('id', id)),
  mapIndexed((item, key) => ({ ...item, position: key + 1 }))
);

const arr = [{"id":10,"position":1},{"id":11,"position":2},{"id":12,"position":3},{"id":13,"position":4}];

const result = fn(11)(arr);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Array.filter()` to remove and `Array.map()` to re-position the items as following:

```js
const arr = [
  {id: 10, position: 1},
  {id: 11, position: 2},
  {id: 12, position: 3},
  {id: 13, position: 4}
]


repositionedArray = arr.filter(item => item.id != 11).map((item, index) => ({...item, position: index+1}))


console.log(repositionedArray);
```

Hope this helps